# How to show list of articles filtered by category and custom field

Tags: custom-field, joomla-4.x, category-blog

I am looking for a way to show Joomla 4 articles in a category blog filtered by one (or more) of my custom fields. - The category blog settings in the backend seems only allow to filter by category, tag and other default article parameters. - Is filtering a blog by custom fields possible, anyways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter on Custom Fields via **multiple ways**:

- filtering via **JavaScript + CSS**. This will load all articles, but can CSS hide (display:none) them using some JavaScript. The articles are still there in the HTML source but just not visible.
- filtering via **PHP** in **Joomla's Articles Model**. This will load only the articles that fit to the filter state. I used this technique for a client project: I've programmed a System Plugin that overrides Joomla's Articles Model in the `populateState` method. And I programmed a Module to set the Filters. This way I was able to filter the Articles based on Filter Options using some Custom Field Fields.

There are some **3rd party extensions** available that add filtering functionality to Joomla's articles:

- **JL Content Fields Filter** (for J3 + J4) https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jl-content-fields-filter/
- **JFilters** (for J4) https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jfilters/

Comment: I also suggest to check one of the suggested 3rd party extensions. 
No need to re-invent the wheel on that.

Comment: @pe7er could you share your System Plugin code especially on how you overwrite Joomla's Article Model in the populateState method.

Comment: I thought of writing a Plugin for this. It works fine on small projects, but may run into performance issues on larger ones.
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/authoring-a-content/custom-fields/netzsinn-custom-fields-filter/